# How to get all rows and filter rows from ag grid

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am trying to figure out, how can I get all rows from my ag-grid. There is no such method **getAllRows()** in gridapi. Hence I tried below -

```
let deletedRows = [];
    deletedRows = gridApi.forEachNode((node : any)) => {
        if(node.data.action === 'DELETE'){
        deletedRows.push(node.data)
    }
});
```

Here, I'm trying to get all rows and filter rows which action column is **'DELETE'**.
But I'm getting ***deletedRows as undefined***. Could you guys please explain why I'm getting the array as undefined?

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out I was doing a silly mistake here. Here is how I resolved it.

```
let deletedRows : any[] = [];
    gridApi.forEachNode((node : any)) => {
        if(node.data.action === 'DELETE'){
        deletedRows.push(node.data)
    }
});
```